# An abelian Banach algebra without characters

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, banach-algebras

Can one give an example of an abelian Banach algebra with empty character space? Such algebra must be necessarily non-unital.

I couldn't find any examples of such algebras.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess that the OP asks for "a commutative Banach algebra without characters". If so, this is a reasonable question.

Comment: the edit history of this question is very strange, I'm not a CA export but it looks as if the question has been changed to a new question, in place of the OP. Can someone with greater experience please assist?

Comment: @Bacon it appears the OP has decided to edit the question to an entirely different question about complex analysis two years after it was originally asked :)

Comment: @s.harp That was my initial thought, but couldn't be absolutely clear as I'm not a CA expert. I was worried that if I tried to revert as C.Dubussy did I would be in trouble! Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The [Volterra algebra](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VolterraAlgebra.html) $V$ is an example of a commutative Banach algebra without maximal ideals (hence with empty character space). See also Definition 4.7.38 in

> H. G. Dales, *Banach algebras and automatic continuity*, London Math. Soc.
>   Monographs, Volume 24, Clarendon Press, Oxford, 2000.

Okay, let me prove this claim. This relies on three facts:

The algebra $V$ has a bounded approximate identity, *e.g.* $(n\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\big[0, \tfrac{1}{n}\big]})_{n=1}^\infty$, hence by the [Cohen factorisation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Hewitt_factorization_theorem), $V = V^2$. Consequently, [all maximal ideals of $V$ (if exist) are closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859247/maximal-ideals-and-maximal-subspaces-of-normed-algebras/863704#863704).

Now apply a result of Dixmier which tells you that no prime ideal of $V$ is closed. Of course, maximal ideals are prime so, the conclusion follows. You will find the proof of Dixmier's result in the above-mentioned book by Dales (Theorem 4.7.58).

Comment: Thanks for your answer
But I think there is a maximal ideal in the Volterra algebra  For example, suppose set M={f \in L^1([0,1]) : f(1)=0 }. Is not a maximal ideal in the  Volterra algebra?

Comment: Is this set closed under multiplication (convolution)?

Comment: in my idea your answer is right, but unfortunately because i can not find your refrences, i don't find out your proof.

Comment: You only need Dixmier's result. I will sketch it over the weekend for you.

Comment: thanks for your reply and your time

Comment: I wonder if there are any "easy" examples, like $L^p$ spaces or continuous functions. Of course these are all non-examples but something "common" would be nice. Alas, I don't know any "common" algebra that has empty character space : (

Comment: As far as I know from Garth Dales, this is the *standard example* of an algebra without maximal ideals.

Answer (score 0):

A related comment: I think I have an example of a commutative unital complex algebra $A$ without 
any nontrivial complex homomorphisms. Take 
$A$ to be all rational functions with complex coefficients, that is 
$$
A= \{[p/q]: p,q \text{ complex polynomials and }q \text{ not identically } 0\}.
$$
Here $[p/q]$ denotes the equivalence class of $(p,q)$ under the relation
$(p,q)\sim(r,s)$ if $ps=qr$. Then $A$ is a commutative unital complex algebra (which is also a field, and the only maximal ideal is $0$). But there is no nontrivial complex homomorphism $\varphi:A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, because if $\varphi(z)=\alpha$, then 
$$
\varphi\Big(\frac{1}{z-\alpha}\Big)=\frac{1}{\varphi(z-\alpha)}=\frac{1}{0},
$$ 
a contradiction.

Comment: what is the norm ?...

Comment: This is an infinite-dimensional field, hence it is not a Banach algebra under any norm.